# Some users can't install app since installLocation is added to the manifest

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, app2sd

Since I added the install location to the manifest (tried both auto and preferExternal) and made my update available in the Market I get some users that can't install the application on their (so far only HTC Desire with Froyo) devices. Is there any known issue on this? Or better a working solution?

I got also the following workaround from a user. Unmount the SD card, install the app, and mount the SD card again does succesfull install the app.

Comment: have you eventually figured it out? It looks like I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a specific error with this specific device model. Your app cannot help that much. But, among some hacks, the device owner can also try this:

[How to Install Apps to the SD Card by Default on Android 2.2 Froyo](http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-on-android-2-2-froyo/)